# How to fetch meaningful rows affected count from the log table sysssislog?

Tags: sql, ssis

I  am trying to get an output from SSIS log, into an SQL Server table which will show me the row numbers that have been commited.

Example in picture which I got from this query

```
SELECT id,
       message
FROM sysssislog
WHERE SOURCE = 'client import package'
  AND message LIKE '%rows%'
```

[image]

It seems the output isn't far off, but I can't really check as it's all `OLE DB destination` where the hell do I change this setting?

My output would idealy read something like:
Component "Data Transfer Quotations wrote 7752 rows"
Data Transfer being the name of one of my tasks...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Could you restate what the final product would be were someone to answer your question. What is incorrect about your supplied query?

Comment: Hi, I've made the edit hopefully this is more clear./

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the name of the `OLE DB Destination` within each `Data Flow Task`.

Here is a very simple package that imports text file into SQL Server table. The flat file looks as shown below.

[image: Flat File]

The data flow task within the SSIS package is configured as shown below. It reads the file and passes the file output to two different OLE DB Destinations. NOTE: You can notice that each OLE DB Destination is given an appropriate names like **`All records`** and **`Only 123`**. This is what shows up in the log table `sysssislog`. Logging is enabled on the SSIS package.

[image: Data flow task]

When I run the following query in my logging database, I will notice the component name and the number of records inserted by each OLE DB Destination component.

```
select  id
,       message 
from    sysssislog 
where   source = 'so_14560087' 
and     message like '%rows%'
```

I believe that this is what you are looking for. I assume that in your case you have multiple data flow tasks and `OLE DB Destination` within each data flow task is left with the default name OLE DB Destination. That is the reason you see the same name in the log tables. You can simply click on the `OLE DB Destination` component within each data flow task and provide an appropriate name for your to check the status.

[image: Log table]

Comment: Strange, I've done this and I'm still getting some OLE DB etc... I've done a search on the Output window and they're not in there. It must be some kind of oversight on my part, thanks for your help.